# Pass a regular expression as a parameter to a shell script

Tags: regex, bash, shell, parameters

How to pass a regular expression as a parameter to a shell script?

I need to write a shell script, which will take parameters and give them to unix commands. And I'd like to use regular expressions there. Is this possible at all?

Or reformulation - how to write the script equivalent to "cp" command, using only this command?

I'm trying to make a file "mycp"

```
#!/bin/bash -fx
cp $2 $1
```

and call it by

```
mycp myDir "*sh"
```

and want it to do the same as "cp *sh myDir".
But resulting bash interpretation is:

```
+ cp '*sh' myDir
cp: *sh: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You say 'I need to write a shell, which will...'; do you mean a shell or a shell script?  The complexity of writing a shell is vastly bigger than writing a shell script.  When you say 'regex', do you mean 'shell glob expressions'?  What do you mean by 'write script equivalent to `cp` command, using only this command'?  Only using `cp`, or only using shell script and not `cp`?  Or ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Revised question

> I'm trying to make a file "mycp"
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash -fx
> cp $2 $1
> ```
>
> and call it by
>
> ```
> mycp myDir "*sh"
> ```

In that case, you still need `eval`, but you'd write:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
eval cp "$2" "$1"
```

You're running into problems because you have specified the `-f` option.  `man bash` says (in part):

> After word splitting, unless the `-f` option has been set, bash scans each word for the  characters `*`, `?`, and `[`.

Remove the `f` from the 'shebang' (first) line of the script.

---

#### Original question

Given that you want `mycp "*sh*" aa` to do shell expansion on the argument, you'll probably end up using `eval` in your script:

```
eval cp "$@"
```

However, the use of `eval` is dangerous; it can lead to unexpected side-effects.  The use of `"$@"` is important; it preserves the number of arguments and spaces in them.  Unfortunately, using `eval` then undoes that, but we can't have everything — or not easily.

---

For quite a long time (say 1987<sup>*</sup> to 1999), I used this script as a cover for `cp`:

```
:   "@(#)$Id: cp.sh,v 1.3 1997/06/02 21:45:00 johnl Exp $"
#
#   Alternative copy command

case $# in
0)  /bin/cp     ;;
1)  /bin/cp $1 .    ;;
2)  /bin/cp "$@"    ;;
*)  if [ -d `la "$@"` ]
    then    /bin/cp "$@"
    else    /bin/cp "$@" .
    fi;;
esac
```

It uses a very simple C program called `la` (for 'last argument') to get the last argument and checks whether the given last argument is a directory.  More than 99% of the time, if I typed (by accident) 'cp /some/where/*sh*' rather than `cp /some/where/*sh* .`, the second was what I meant, and the script fixed things.  I haven't used it for quite some time; it may have been in the last millennium, but was probably sometime earlier in this one that I gave up using it.

<sup>*</sup> *Although the version string says '1997', the code is identical to the 1987 version.  Version 1.1 and 1.2 were under SCCS and used different SCCS ID strings; the conversion to RCS made them identical.  Version 1.3 reinstated the `@(#)` identifier string used by the SCCS `what` command to the RCS version handling.  So, the script is ancient — 1987, really.*

Comment: well that was just example. suppose I need to do it backward: mycp arg1 arg2 equivalent to cp arg2 arg1

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `eval cp $1 $2`

[Bash reference manual: eval](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-eval-112)

Comment: well eval gives the same + eval cp '*sh' aa
++ cp '*sh' aa
cp: *sh: No such file or directory

Comment: Works fine for me. Please provide extra info: at least `ls` listing on your working directory

Comment: The  'f' in '`#!/bin/bash -fx` is making the difference.  It suppresses wild-card expansion, so it will work for you, Nya, but not for @klm123.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is specify the directory first, look at the `-t` option to GNU cp:

```
alias mycp='cp -t'
mycp mydir *.sh
```

Otherwise:

```
mycp() {
  local dir=$1
  shift
  cp "$@" "$dir"
}
mycp mydir *.sh
```

Either way, let the shell expand the wildcards and avoid the use of `eval`

(note, `*.sh` is not a regular expression, it's a [shell "pattern"](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching), often referred to as a "glob pattern")